# How to make fighting game command inputs in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a fighting game and was wondering how command inputs could be added. I understand it is kind of irrelevant and many substitutes are possible, but it would be nice to use familiar fighting game inputs.

I currently have something like this:

```
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            commandcount +=1
            if commandcount > 0 and commandcount < 30 and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[pygame.K_z]:               
                player1.projectile = True
```

The "commandcount" helps keep the window of action available until a certain amount of time.

The main problem with this is that you could still press the inputs in whatever order and the projectile would still come out.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the pygame.KEYDOWN events instead of pygame.key.get_pressed() so the order can be observed. Use a list to keep track of the order of these KEYDOWN events. When the order matches a specific combo then execute the move and reset the list. The list also gets reset after a certain amount of time with a combo. I made an example program with the combo down, right, z activating a fireball.

```
import pygame

# pygame setup
pygame.init()

# Open a window on the screen
width, height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    move_combo = []
    frames_without_combo = 0

    while True:
        clock.tick(30)  # number of loops per second
        frames_without_combo += 1

        if frames_without_combo > 30 or len(move_combo) > 2:
            print("COMBO RESET")
            frames_without_combo = 0
            move_combo = []

        screen.fill(black)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                move_combo.append(event.key)  # Only keys for combos should be added

        if move_combo == [pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_z]:
            print("FIRE BALL")
            frames_without_combo = 0
        print(move_combo)
        pygame.display.update()


main()
```